# Chrome extension with OAuth2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am trying to create a Chrome Extension which would save some data to the user's Google Drive. I figured `OAuth` would be the best way to go about it. So I do the following in `manifest.json`:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<my_client_id>",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
}
```

After that, I want to use the Google API for authentication in my `background.js` using `gapi.auth.authorize` etc. However even if I include `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js` in background scripts of manifest, it still can not find it. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to use OAuth?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681803/loading-google-api-javascript-client-library-into-chrome-extension) is your question, basically. You are trying to include a remote script which is forbidden by the default CSP. This can be relaxed; see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681803/loading-google-api-javascript-client-library-into-chrome-extension) for more details.

> Is there a better way to use OAuth?

Yes, [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity). You can take a look at a [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/gdrive) provided by Google.